# How do I replace a value in an array?

Tags: bash

In the following array

```
ARR=(
"xxx" "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
"xxx" "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
"xxx" "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
"xxx" "ssssssssssssss"
"xxx" "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
"xxx" "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
)
```

I need to replace the  value `ssssssssssssss` with  `xxxxxxxxxxxxxx`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use parameter expansion and substitution:

```
ARR=("${ARR[@]/ssssssssssssss/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply assign new value:

```
ARR[7]="xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

If you don't know the position of "ssss..." string, you can interate over array:

```
i=0
for item in ${ARR[*]}
do
        if [ "$item" == "ssssssssssssss" ]
        then
                ARR[$i]="xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        fi
        ((i++));
done
```

Comment: OK, but do not know the ID of the field :-(